# expo EAS build (iOS) fails in Pod installation step (SDK45 & 46)

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo, cocoapods

I am trying to build iOS app (simulator) from expo managed project. The build fails At Pod installation step.

In Expo SDK 44 everything is okay. But when I upgrade to SDK 45 or even 46, I am facing the issue.

Here are some logs from expo server:

**Run Expo Doctor**

```
Running "expo doctor"
- Finding all copies of expo-modules-autolinking
- Finding all copies of @expo/config-plugins
[stderr] 
[02:48:23] Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.0
[stderr] 
[02:48:23] Found invalid:
[stderr] 
[02:48:23]   @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
[stderr] 
[02:48:23]   (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
- Finding all copies of @expo/prebuild-config
- Finding all copies of @unimodules/core
- Finding all copies of @unimodules/react-native-adapter
- Finding all copies of react-native-unimodules
[stderr] 
[02:48:28] Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
[stderr] 
[02:48:28]  - react - expected version: 18.0.0 - actual version installed: 17.0.2
[stderr] 
[02:48:28]  - react-dom - expected version: 18.0.0 - actual version installed: 17.0.2
[stderr] 
[02:48:28]  - react-native - expected version: 0.69.4 - actual version installed: 0.68.2
[stderr] 
[02:48:28] Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
[stderr] 
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo doctor --fix-dependencies,
[stderr] 
or install individual packages by running expo install [package-name ...]
[stderr] 
[02:48:31] Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.68.2 for expo sdkVersion 46.0.0. Use react-native@0.69.4
Command "expo doctor" failed.
bash exited with non-zero code: 1
```

**Install Pods**

```
Installing pods
Using Expo modules
Auto-generating `.xcode.env.local` with $NODE_BINARY=/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `Classima`: RNDateTimePicker, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, lottie-react-native, react-native-maps, react-native-netinfo, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-slider, react-native-webview, and stripe-react-native
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RCT-Folly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    RCT-Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`)
  In Podfile:
    RCT-Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`)
It seems like you've changed the version of the dependency `RCT-Folly` and it differs from the version stored in `Pods/Local Podspecs`.
You should run `pod update RCT-Folly --no-repo-update` to apply changes made locally.
Error: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:
 - Versions in the Podfile.lock cached by EAS do not match required values for some of the libraries, it can be triggered when upgrading Expo SDK or any other library with native code. To fix that add the "cache.key" field (it can be set to any value) in the build profile in eas.json to invalidate the cache.
 - Some of your npm packages have native code that depend on different versions of the same pod. Please see logs for more info.
```

**Fail Build**

```
Build failed: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:
  - Versions in the Podfile.lock cached by EAS do not match required values for some of the libraries, it can be triggered when upgrading Expo SDK or any other library with native code. To fix that add the "cache.key" field (it can be set to any value) in the build profile in eas.json to invalidate the cache.
  - Some of your npm packages have native code that depend on different versions of the same pod. Please see logs for more info.
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

eas build -p ios --clear-cache

Comment: Thanks! I ran into this today, super frustrating. Adding `--clear-cache` worked for me.

Comment: This was just an awesome answer :)

Answer (score 8):

I am facing the same issue, i tried "eas build -p ios --clear-cache" but nothing changed. The build fails at the pod install

Here are the logs:

````
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `BallNConnect`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNDateTimePicker, RNDeviceInfo, RNFBApp, RNFBFirestore, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, lottie-ios, lottie-react-native, react-native-maps, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
CocoaPods 1.11.3 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.3
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-google-maps (from `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.29.4, which depends on
      Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (= 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
        GoogleMaps
    react-native-google-maps (from `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.29.4, which depends on
      GoogleMaps (= 3.5.0)
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "nanopb":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 7.7.0) was resolved to 7.7.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (= 7.7.0) was resolved to 7.7.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
    RNFBFirestore (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore`) was resolved to 12.9.3, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 8.8.0) was resolved to 8.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (~> 8.8.0) was resolved to 8.8.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
[stderr] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `6D6F16C9EE89401295D6CEB6` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Error: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:
  - Versions in the Podfile.lock cached by EAS do not match required values in Podspecs of some of the libraries. To fix that add the "cache.key" field (it can be set to any value) in the build profile in eas.json to invalidate the cache.
  - Some of the pods used in your project depend on different versions of the same pod. See logs for more information.```
````